# How to implement Print preview functionality in java

Tags: java, swt

I am developing a web browser in Java using SWT components. How can I implement Print preview functionality?

---

As I said in my, I am using SWT for application develpment, We can download the SWT source code and in this source code we add our functionality in browser class.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

may be this will help
http://developeriq.in/articles/2010/mar/03/generating-print-preview-from-java/

Comment: Thansks but i m using SWT components and like to print preview of a web page